# Room Reservation System - Ideas (non technical)

Tags: system

Need suggestions on room reservation system. Posting it as I couldn't find a similar question here in SO.

**Question:** Can I use wordpress and create my own plugin using php/mysql for a very simple and straight-forward room reservation system (4 page workflow)? If not what are the possibilites, Please suggest.

If the post is not in the right forum, please feel free to close it or re-direct me.

**Background:** I work part time for a non profit organization (I dont get paid, it's just a service to the community during my free time). They own a small property with about 20-30 rooms onsite and manage their room reservations, manually with Google drive.

I've suggested them to build an online portal for reservation. This is a service project, to enhance my technical resume as well as help someone.

**My technical abilities** - HTML, CSS, VB, SQL, PL-sQL (A long time ago) and I'm an automation tester so very good with programming skills.

**Project deadline** -  4 to 6 months. (I'd be spending about 15 hours/week)

PS: If this is beyond my capabilities I will be asking them to outsource.

Comment: if you can't help, that's okay. Need not share your attitude here.

Answer (score 4):

Did you look at SourceForge, etc, to see if you can get a ready made system for free?

You may have to tailor it a little, but it might still be the quickest & easiest way to get somethign up & running. Your skills seem fine, though (VB is fine for a Windows app, you would want PHP for web-based).

Take a look at

- [Meeting Room Booking System](http://mrbs.sourceforge.net/) is a free, GPL, web application using PHP and MySQL/pgsql for booking meeting rooms or other resources.
- [Meeting Room Reservation System](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reservation/), a mock project for study purpose.
- [phpScheduleIt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpscheduleit/), a web-based resource scheduling system
- [OpenRoom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openroom/) provides a simple online interface for managing and reserving rooms
- RoomTimes is a php written application with which you can manage the rooms of any organisation

or you might want to [google for others](https://www.google.com.sg/#q=freeware+room+reservation)

Comment: **Meeting Room Booking System** it's good like a start solution!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Pelase don't forget to let us know what you decided, for the sake of others who search & find this question in the future.